# How can I easily support duplicate async/sync methods?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

Entity framework has synchronous and asynchronous versions of the same IO-bound methods such as `SaveChanges` and `SaveChangesAsync`. How can I create new methods that minimally accomplish the same task without "duplicating" code?

```
public bool SaveChanges()
{
    //Common code calling synchronous methods
    context.Find(...);

    //Synchronous Save
    return context.SaveChanges();
}

public async Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync()
{
    //Common code asynchronous methods
    await context.FindAsync(...);    

    //Asynchronous Save
    return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't - at least, not sensibly. Synchronous and asynchronous implementations are **fundamentally different**. You can *fake over it*, via "sync over async" and "async over sync", but both of these are anti-patterns and should be avoided.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that EF accomplishes this by duplicating the code?

Comment: @Shoe it is *entirely possible* that EF accomplishes this by duplicating the code; I wouldn't necessarily *assume* it; however - since it is most likely a mix of code-gen and meta-programming, it is probably fine (i.e. "done right").

Comment: If I had cpu-bound methods instead of io-bound, would the correct way to accomplish this be to use something like `Task.Run()`?

Comment: @Shoe quite possibly, but even that depends a lot on things like expected duration

Comment: @Shoe Pretty much any time you ever see synchronous IO operations it is, at a conceptual level, sync over async.  Just about every type of IO out there is conceptually asynchronous.  It is made synchronous by blocking on the asynchronous operation.  Now, as Marc, said, you can generally trust library implementations to do this as best they can, avoiding what problems are avoidable.

Comment: the key thing to add there is that there are good ways to block on async, and bad ways. For example, if you have a `Task`, calling `Wait()` is usually *bad* - that could be an instant deadlock. Hence why sync and async are usually quite different beasts.